# Can I get a pointer to a Span?

Tags: c#, .net-standard-2.0, .net-4.6, .net-core-2.1

I have a `(ReadOnly)Span<byte>` from which I want to decode a string.

Only in .NET Core 2.1 I have the new overload to decode a string from it without needing to copy the bytes:

```
Encoding.GetString(ReadOnlySpan<byte> bytes);
```

In .NET Standard 2.0 and .NET 4.6 (which I also want to support), I only have the classic overloads:

```
Encoding.GetString(byte[] bytes);
Encoding.GetString(byte* bytes, int byteCount);
```

The first one requires a copy of the bytes into an array which I want to avoid.
The second requires a byte pointer, so I thought about getting one from my span, like

```
Encoding.GetString(Unsafe.GetPointer<byte>(span.Slice(100)))
```

...but I failed finding an actual method for that. I tried `void* Unsafe.AsPointer<T>(ref T value)`, but I cannot pass a span to that, and didn't find another method dealing with pointers (and spans).

Is this possible at all, and if yes, how?

Comment: Enter `[ReadOnly]Span<T>.GetPinnableReference()`. If using C# 7.3, leveraging this is as simple as `fixed (byte* bytes = span)` -- this compiles for .NET 4.5.2, at least, I haven't tested if it will also really *work* (I only have later frameworks installed).

Comment: In prior C# versions, you can use the return value of `ref GetPinnableReference()` as the argument to `Unsafe.AsPointer`. You need at least C# 7.0 to use `ref` locals.

Comment: @JeroenMostert This is great, I'm using C# 7.3 and it's working smooth as silk. Do you want to post an answer about it so I can accept it?

Comment: With the help of ILSpy, I actually found a more convenient syntax for earlier versions as well. Also not tested, but since the pointers returned are identical I'm going to assume it works.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

If you have C# 7.3 or later, you can use the extension made to the `fixed` statement that can use any appropriate `GetPinnableReference` method on a type (which `Span` and `ReadOnlySpan` have):

```
fixed (byte* bp = bytes) {
    ...
}
```

As we're dealing with pointers this requires an `unsafe` context, of course.

C# 7.0 through 7.2 don't have this, but allow the following:

```
fixed (byte* bp = &bytes.GetPinnableReference()) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Span<byte> bytes = ...;
string s = Encoding.UTF8.GetString((byte*)Unsafe.AsPointer(ref bytes.GetPinnableReference()),
    bytes.Length);
```

Comment: Thanks! I did not see `GetPinnableReference()` anywhere in IntelliSense. However, this did not seem to work for `ReadOnlySpan<byte>` (it cannot pass it as ref because it is readonly); but it would work for my initial question (only now I realized I have a `ReadOnlySpan`, sorry!).

Comment: @RayKoopa: the reason you couldn't see the method, by the way, is because it was [explicitly hidden as feature](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/18747). This was back when it was called `DangerousGetPinnableReference`; it's since been downgraded to "not actually that dangerous", but the method's still hidden.

Comment: The alternative proposed for `ReadOnlySpan` is not correct! Storing it in a variable first and taking the `ref` of that gives you a reference to the local `byte`, *not* the spanned array. Accessing any element beyond the first this way will give garbage.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I actually remember that "Dangerous" method name. I didn't follow up on the recent changes, thanks for clearing this up.